# OCMOD searching whem i have line breaks or undefined whitespaces

Tags: regex, search, opencart, ocmod

im trying to make a OCmod for opencart 2.0.3.1
and when i try to find in catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl

these two parts of html code the script dont find anything in error log its says NOT FOUND.

the first search is that

```html
<search>
 <![CDATA[
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
 ]]>
</search>
```

and the seccond serach if for that

```html
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

both of this searchs not find any thing but i copied and pasted from the original file.
some one can help me to improve this serach whit regex or tell me how ocmod works to serach that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample OCMod code to do more better search in your opencart 2.x version.

```
<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[}}]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[This is test ocmod]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

**This is test ocmod** text display after } }
Try this kind of code in your ocmod.

Comment: this is my code 
<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
  <operation>
   <search regex="true">
    <![CDATA[~<?php } ?>\s<?php } ?>~]]>
   </search>
   <add position="after">
    <![CDATA[
     my custom code here
    ]]>
   </add>
  </operation>
 </file>